# AzCopy Sync command is failing on access key but passing on SAS key when container is private

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the Azcopy sync command. It passes when I used the SAS key. But fails when I use the access key. Access key works when the blob is public though. Why does the access key fail when the blob is private?

I run the command from a VM whose vnet is allowed in the selected networks. And blob public access is disabled.

This is how I pass both keys

```
"https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/container?sv=KEY"
```

This is the error I get

```
RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=PublicAccessNotPermitted) =====
 RESPONSE Status: 409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
```

Comment: Could you please provide your command when you do that with access key?

Comment: @JimXu edited the question to add key

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: I post a new answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we use `azcopy sync` command to sync files between Azure Blob storage or between Azure Blob and local spaces, it does not support do auth with access key. It just supports SAS or OAuth authentication. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#synopsis).
[image]

For example(I use SAS  authentication)

1. Create sas token via Azure Portal
   [image]
   [image]
2. Sync

```
azcopy sync '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>?<the sas token you copy in step1>' --recursive
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provide, you want to use `azcopy` command to sync file with shared access signatures. If so, the shared access signatures should be like `sv=2019-02-02&ss=bf&srt=s&st=2019-08-01T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2019-08-10T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&spr=https&sig=<>`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#option-2-use-a-sas-token).

For example

1. Create sas token via Azure Portal
   [image]
   [image]
2. Sync

```
azcopy sync '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>?<the sas token you copy in step1>' --recursive
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: " you want to use azcopy command to sync file with shared access signatures" this is not true. This is working

Comment: @BlueClouds Could you please tell me what you want to implement?

Comment: Use access key instead of sas key when the blob is private

Comment: @BlueClouds The command `azcopy sync` does not support do auth with access key. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#synopsis

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Can this is posted as answer?